# Como exibir dados de três tabelas numa view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Possuo três tabelas: Processo, Andamento e Custas: 
como faço para exibir os dados das três em uma  View, sendo que as tabelas Andamento e Custas possuem como chave estrangeira, a chave primária de Processo?

Fiz um foreach para cada tabela, mas não deu certo, fica duplicando os dados.

```
        <div class="row">                         
            <strong>Sentença/Acórdão:</strong>
            <?php echo $processo[0]->sentenca; ?>         
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">                         
            <p><font size="3" face="helvetica"><strong>Andamentos</strong></font></p>             
        </div>     
        <div class="row">        
            <div class="table-responsive">                                   
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary hidden-print" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".addandamento"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>  
                <table class="table table-striped">                                         
                    <?php foreach ($processo as $proc) { ?>
                        <tr class="row">                                
                            <td width="14%"><font color="#000000" size="2" face="tahoma"><b><?= $proc->dtandamento; ?></b></font></td>
                            <td width="78%"><font color="#000000" size="2" face="tahoma"><b><?= $proc->descricao; ?></b></font></td>                            
                        </tr>  
                    <?php } ?>                    
                </table>
            </div>             
        </div>                  
        <div class="row">        
        <div class="table-responsive">                                   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary hidden-print" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".addandamento"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>  
            <table class="table table-striped">                                         
                <?php foreach ($processo as $proc) { ?>
                    <tr class="row">                                
                        <td width="14%"><font color="#000000" size="2" face="tahoma"><b><?= $proc->dtcustas; ?></b></font></td>
                        <td width="78%"><font color="#000000" size="2" face="tahoma"><b><?= $proc->descricao_custas; ?></b></font></td>                            
                    </tr>  
                <?php } ?>                    
            </table>
        </div>                       
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você passou os dados pra view? Insira seu código!

Comment: @AndréBaill coloquei na pergunta o código da view.

Comment: Ok e o codigo de controller e model?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi certo, mas isso você resolve com as models, fazendo um select que faça os JOINS entre as três tabelas, algo como:

`SELECT * FROM Processo INNER JOIN Andamento ON Andamento.id_processo = Processo.id INNER JOIN Custas ON Custas.id_processo = Processo.id ...;`

Isso usando as funções do `$this->db` do codeigniter, como:

```
    $this->db->from('Processo');
    $this->db->join('Andamento', 'Andamento.id_processo=Processo.id');
    $this->db->join('Custas', 'Custas.id_processo=Custas.id');
```

Que retornará um array, o qual você deve iterar em sua view.

Comment: @IpFranz eu já tinha feito os joins, o problema é que a view mostra os dados de ambas as tabelas (Andamento e Custas) de forma duplicada. Acho que tem a haver com os foreach, mas ainda não enxerguei o problema.

Comment: Isso parece que pode ser resolvido com um `GROUP BY`, não?

Comment: @IpFranz o group_by resolveu para a tabela Andamento, mas agora a tabela Custas só exibi o primeiro registro :(

Comment: Como são os relacionamentos entre essas tabelas? Há Vários Andamentos/Custas para cada processo? Precisaria ver o banco pra conseguir ajudar melhor

Comment: vou postar o print das tabelas na pergunta, pode ser?

Comment: Código do Model:

function get_processos_like() {
        $termo = $this->input->post('pesquisar');
        $this->db->join('andamento', 'fkcodprocesso=codprocesso', 'left');
        $this->db->join('custas', 'fkcodproc=codprocesso', 'left');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('nprocesso', $termo);        
        $this->db->order_by ("str_to_date(andamento.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y')", 'DESC', FALSE);        
        $this->db->group_by ('andamento.dtandamento');
        return $this->db->get('processo')->result();
}